# typeError htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array in laravel for toast warning message

Tags: laravel

htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\teletherapy-laravel\resources\views\frontend\layouts\alerts.blade.php).How to fix this issue ? I am not able to see toast?

```
Below is my code:
**In controller I use:**
 return Redirect::back()->with('warning',['Request is already sent']);
**toast message code:** 

@if ($message = Session::get('success'))
    
    @if(is_array(session('success')))

    @foreach (session('success') as $success)
    <script>
        toastr["success"]("{{ $success }}")
    </script>
    @endforeach
    @else
    <script>
        toastr["success"]("{{ $message }}")
    </script>
    
    @endif
@endif

@if ($message = Session::get('error'))

    @if(is_array(session('error')))

    @foreach (session('error') as $succe)
        @php
            $err = $succe ."<br/>";

        @endphp
    @endforeach
   
   
    <script>
        toastr["error"]("{{ $err }}")
    </script>
    @else
    <script>
        toastr["error"]("{{ $message }}")
    </script>

    @endif
    
@endif


@if ($message = Session::get('warning'))
    <script>
        toastr["warning"]("{{ $message }}")
    </script>
@endif
```

Comment: most probably this is because you are trying to use curly braces on `$message`, in JS file, as far as I can understand, it is an array, and you are trying to do a strong operation on array that is not allowed. if this does not help, try debugging each variable within curly braces.

Comment: sry, a string operation on array. have you managed to fix it?